# Ubuntu root permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chef

I am trying to setup a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with chef. I am getting this error, which I'm assuming is related to my user permissions:

```
Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 5.613887095 seconds
[2014-04-13T09:44:41+09:00] ERROR: service[ssh] (basic-security-tlq::default line 59) had an error: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -n -f ssh remove
[2014-04-13T09:44:41+09:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

edit: these are the permissions for the file mentioned in the err log:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root     16894 Apr 14  2012 update-rc.d
```

I've setup other servers (with ubuntu 12.04) using this recipe with no issues, but this is being run on a machine with a different hosting provider. I'm temped to ssh in and start `chmod`ing file, but that seems a bit drastic. The chef recipe is cooked as `root` which is confusing me even more as I thought this user had full permissions?

This may be more appropriate for stackOverflow, but since it's permissions related I thought I'd try here first.

update2: I tried doing `chown root update-rc.d` and it still throws the same error. I am starting to wonder if it isn't an SSL problem because of this line in the error
`ERROR: service[ssh]`, but not sure how to investigate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to update the ssh daemon using update-rc.d and it's not being allowed to. Try doing it by hand to see what the problem is. It'll be far easier to diagnose from the errors you see from running it from the command line as root. Try this:

## /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -n -f ssh remove

It really doesn't have anything to do with the permissions you revealed of update-rc.d.

Comment: cheers, running it from command line gave me ```-bash: /usr/sbin/update-rc.d: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: Permission denied``` which I fixed by doing ```chmod``` on the perl file. I'm not sure if that was the correct way to fix the issue, but the chef script completes now

Comment: That was exactly the right way to fix it. Good going. There's no good reason at all why that perl binary didn't have its world executable bit set.